# WebRtc Architecture - Are videos stored by Webrtc?

Tags: webrtc

I have a simple question. After peer connection is established how video is transmitted from Peer. Does the video go to some Server of webrtc for transcoding? Or is stored somewhere by webrtc temporarily/permanently? If it is stored do they use the data for any processing or share with businesses.

Answer (score 3):

WebRTC isn't a company. It's a browser API and set of protocols. There's no central entity video data goes through. WebRTC defines a way in which data can be sent peer-to-peer directly between two browsers. No third party involved, just two browsers.

* Having said that, often you'll involve STUN servers to aid in establishing the connection, but no actual video data ever goes through STUN. You may also have TURN servers, which do relay video data if no direct connection is possible. You will typically have to explicitly configure a list of TURN servers to use, so you have control over that. You may also use a transcoding server in the middle, which may also store the data, but that is again something you very explicitly set up and configure.

Comment: Thanks man. Even i thought so but today i had a pretty serious debate with an experienced person and he was very adamant that videos have to be stored somewhere. He says that video data can be as large as 30 mb to 100 mb so it need to be stored before it is transmitted to peer. And how secure is the communication?

Comment: Well, it's a *realtime video stream*, so no, beyond whatever small buffer is necessary for the implementation, nothing is being stored (again, unless you explicitly do record and store it somewhere).

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23300741/476.