# How to stream WebRTC to WebSocket?

Tags: opencv, websocket, webrtc, autobahn, ffserver

Hi I want to stream a **WebRTC** (**MediaStream**) video to a **WebSocket** (**Twisted**+**Autobahn**) and process the stream for **OpenCV** object detection and send it back to the client via **FFServer** (**FFMPeg**)?

I have try using only WebRTC, WebSocket and OpenCV, but the streaming is not real-time.

Comment: What do you think of [this](https://github.com/Computician/WebSocketWebRTCRecorders)? It does not send the stream directly, but sends images and audio packets in real time over a websocket that you provide. Disclaimer, I wrote it.

Comment: Thats nice, thanks. But my requirements is python.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

WebRTC has its own way of sending media, and it uses DTLS-SRTP as transport in a channel established with ICE.

WebSockets are based on a TCP connection from client to server in order to send raw data in both directions.

You can check [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491377/sending-webrtc-mediastream-over-websocket-rtp-over-http-websocket?rq=1) for more info.